# Upload file to Dropbox from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dropbox-api, fs

I am trying to upload a file from Node.js to my dropbox account. I have created an app on dropbox developer console and then generated a Access Token.

I am using the following code to read and upload a file to dropbox:

```
app.get('/uploadfile', function (req, res) {

  if (req.query.error) {
    return res.send('ERROR ' + req.query.error + ': ' + req.query.error_description);
  }

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/files/pictureicon.png','utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    fileupload(data);
  });
});

function fileupload(content) {
  request.put('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/proposals/icon.png', {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN-HERE', 'Content-Type': 'image/png'
  }, body: content}, function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, bodymsg) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    } 

    console.log("HERE");
  });
}
```

By using the above code my file appears in my dropbox account but I am unable to open it. It comes up with the following error.

[image]

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Am I making a mistake in the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you read the file with the encoding `utf-8`, even though it is not a text file. You should read the buffer (by simply [not providing a encoding argument](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)).

Comment: Yup that was problem. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late hope this will help someone,

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

  const uploadFile = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios({
            method: `POST`,
            url: `https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload`,
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
              'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path":"/testfolder/isp.png"}',//file path of dropbox
            },
            data: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/isp.png'),//local path to uploading file
          });
          console.log(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
          return console.log(`X ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
```